# Adding a Product Attribute in magento 2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1

I am trying to create attribute for sorting.setup:upgrade showing no error at all but data is not being saved in database. I cannot see it in eav_attribute table or in catalog_eav_attribute table. I tried all the possible ways which are explained here but all in vain.

**code for InstallData.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
 /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'sorting_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'Sorting Attribute',
                'input' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => ''
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**module.xml file:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module"  setup_version="1.0.0">
     <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

I also tried this code in InstallData.php as suggested here

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;


/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        /* assign object to class global variable for use in other class methods */
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
         $setup->startSetup();
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);


        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
       */
       $eavSetup->addAttribute(
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
       'sorting_attribute',
       [
       'type' => 'int',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Sorting Attribute',
        'input' => 'text',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => '',
        'global' => 1,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'default' => 0,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => true,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,virtual,bundle,downloadable,grouped',
        'group'=> 'General'
       ]
      );
```

**Also made these changes**

> \Magento\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL to
>   \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL.

**Anybody can help me out that what are the other possible errors.**

Comment: I have tested your first InstallData.php and it's working (with a little change: 'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL).  Have you tried to clear the cache? ..try to remove manually the var/cache, var/page_cache, var/generation